# Obtener un registro específico de un Array JSON usando un servicio web

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, rest

Estoy utilizando este servicio para obtener un listado de posts, funciona perfectamente, sin embargo, necesito obtener el detalle de cada uno de ellos por lo que en la url de la pantalla del listado le paso el parametro ID que recojo en la pantalla de detalle (vía GET, mejor POST, pero de momento es GET). Necesito mediante ese parámetro recoger el registro correspondiente. Este es el servicio que me muestra el listado.

```
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                app.readPosts();
            });
            var app = {
                posts_url: "http://www.url.com/tareas_home.json",
                onDeviceReady: function() {
                    console.log('Device is ready');
                    app.readPosts();        
                },
                readPosts: function() {
                    console.log('Leyendo listado');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: app.posts_url,
                        success: app.onSuccess,
                        error: app.onError
                    });
                    console.log('Leyendo posts asincrono');
                },
                onSuccess: function(data) {
                    var items = [];
                    $.each(data, function(key, val){        
                        items.push('<div class="card"><div class="card-body"><a href="' + app.posts_url +'?param='+ val.id + '">' + val.id + ' - ' +val.title + '</a></div></div>');
                });
                    $('#posts').html(items.join('<br/>'));
                    console.log('Exiting onSuccess');
                },
                onError: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Data: ' + data);
                    console.log('Status: ' + textStatus);
                    console.log('Error: ' + errorThrown);
                    $("#posts").html('Error while loading posts');
                    console.log('Exiting onError');
                }
            };
```

Que obtiene este Array y lo muestra correctamente en el contenedor asignado dentro del HTML:

```
            [
              {
                "userId": 1,
                "id": 1,
                "fecha": 1,
                "title": "RequeteddTarea para llevar a cabo",
                "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
              },
              {
                "userId": 1,
                "id": 2,
                    "fecha": 2,
                "title": "Tarea para llevar a cabo con titulo especialmente largo y algunos caracteres especiales",
                "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
              },
              {
                "userId": 1,
                "id": 3,
                    "fecha": 3,
                "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
                "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
              },
              {
                "userId": 1,
                "id": 4,
                    "fecha": 4,
                "title": "eum et est occaecati",
                "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"
              }
            ]
```

¿Existe alguna manera de escoger solamente el registro con *ID=x* del listado en JSON usando el mismo servicio? algo del tipo *http :// www. url. com/file.json?id=3* o *url: app.posts_url.id[3]*? Por el contrario debería de obtener ese registro leyendo un nuevo JSON con dicho registro seleccionado?

Comment: lo que planteas es algo que debe tener el backend ya definido. Una alternativa es que puedes filtrar con javascript en la respuesta.

Comment: No amigo, para obtenerlo el servicio debe aceptar esas peticiones y retornar lo que solicites, en este caso **?id=3** debe estar definido en el **Backend** del sistema que responde la petición. Podrias recibir todo y con JavaScript filtrar solo el **userId**

Answer (score 0):

Existe alguna manera de escoger solamente el registro con ID=x del listado en JSON usando el mismo servicio?

La respuesta es si, si se puede filtrar datos de un JSON

```js
var data = [
            {
                "userId": 1,
                "id": 1,
                "fecha": 1,
                "title": "RequeteddTarea para llevar a cabo",
                "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
            },
            {
                "userId": 1,
                "id": 2,
                "fecha": 2,
                "title": "Tarea para llevar a cabo con titulo especialmente largo y algunos caracteres especiales",
                "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
            },
            {
                "userId": 1,
                "id": 3,
                "fecha": 3,
                "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
                "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
            },
            {
                "userId": 1,
                "id": 4,
                "fecha": 4,
                "title": "eum et est occaecati",
                "body": "ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit amet autem assumenda provident rerum culpa\nquis hic commodi nesciunt rem tenetur doloremque ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit"
            }
        ]


        let result = data.filter(item => item.id===3)
        console.log(result)
```

Es lo mejor opción? No, ya hay datos expuestos y si la cantidad de datos es mucha tiene sus efectos el la respuesta del servidor, lo ideal seria una nueva peticion que busque en tu base de datos el regsitro con el id 3